# Syntax Error: Unexpected 'else'

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm a PHP rookie getting thrown the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /home/stripeparse/example.com/create_customer.php on line 33

```
<?php

require_once('/Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
Stripe::setApiKey("APIKEY");

try
{

    Stripe_Customer::create( array(

        "description" => $mobile,

        "email" => $email

    ));

    $SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';

    $response = json_encode(array('result'=>'SUCCESS','customerID'=>$customer->id));

    array_push($jsonarray, $response);

}

catch (Exception $e)
{
    $response = $e -> getMessage(); 

    array_push($jsonarray,$response);

}

else
{

    $response = json_encode(array('result' => 'DATA = FALSE'))

}

print_r($response);

?>
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `else` requires an `if`...

Comment: remove else from your code or add if statement

Comment: `try/catch/else` isn't a valid construct.... did you mean `try/catch/finally`?

Comment: `else` without `if`?

Comment: Do you want the `else` to run always, or only if the `catch` does not trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because you put an [`else`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) statement behind a [`catch`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) statements. [`else`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) statements can only be placed behind [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) or [`else if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) statements.

Answer (score 1):

Random else condition.

```
else
{
    $response = json_encode(array('result' => 'DATA = FALSE'))
}
```

Just use

```
$response = json_encode(array('result' => 'DATA = FALSE'))
```